# For each column group of values order by list without dropping duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

if i have a dataframe like this one:

| level | org |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | A |
| 3 | A |
| 3 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | B |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | B |
| 3 | B |
| 1 | C |
| 1 | C |
| 2 | C |
| 2 | C |
| 3 | C |
| 3 | C |

I want to use a list based on unique values of the level column:

```
levels=[1,2,3]
```

to order each individual org group and get an output like this **preserving the duplicates**:

| level | org |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | A |
| 3 | A |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | A |
| 3 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | B |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | B |
| 1 | C |
| 2 | C |
| 3 | C |
| 1 | C |
| 2 | C |
| 3 | C |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new column with `cumcount`

```
df['new'] = df.groupby(['level','org']).cumcount()
out = df.sort_values(['org','new','level'])
Out[71]: 
    level org  new
0       1   A    0
2       2   A    0
4       3   A    0
1       1   A    1
3       2   A    1
5       3   A    1
6       1   B    0
8       2   B    0
10      3   B    0
7       1   B    1
9       2   B    1
11      3   B    1
12      1   C    0
14      2   C    0
16      3   C    0
13      1   C    1
15      2   C    1
17      3   C    1
```